# How to make "Focus follow mouse" for Dolphin File Explorer?

Tags: terminal, mouse, konsole, dolphin, focus

I use Dolphin file explorer, within which I frequently switch back and forth to the terminal panel. So I was wondering how to make "Focus follow mouse" **within Dolphin**, so that I don't need to click the terminal each time I have to enter something.

I am **not asking about a top-level window. I am asking about panes within one window**. Dolphin has two parts an upper pane a graphical file explorer, and a lower pane containing a terminal.

I noticed that the terminal panel doesn't register as a separate window, as shown by `xprop`.

Comment: There is no "Focus follow mouse" setting for a single window, you need to change the setting for your whole Display Manager (DM). Which one you use, gnome, kde, lxde ? each one has a different sequence to activate the "Focus follow mouse" option.

Comment: I use KDE with i3wm. My current i3 setup already has "Focus follows mouse" enabled.

Comment: So, there are two windows, when you move the mouse over one of them it gets selected, right?. Then what is the problem? Do you need each window to "jump up to the front" so it is clearly visible (not just with focus selected) or something else?

Comment: @isaac OP is not asking about a top-level window. They are asking about pains withing one window. Dolphine has two parts an upper pain a graphical file explorer, and a lower pain containing a terminal.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Thanks for the clarification. You've understood me.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Assuming you mean Dolphin (not dolphine), then yes, I didn't understand the OP request. For which, AFAIK, there is no solution unless the program creators choose to implement it.

Comment: @UtkarshVerma Then: I suggest that you use **two** programs: a file manager and a true terminal.

Comment: Okay, if it's not possible then I'll just have to adjust myself

Comment: @isaac I would not say no solution. But it may be hard. You would need to detect mouse position (or key presses e.g. ctrl-tab), and inject click events.

Answer (score -1):

Look in

- Systemsettings
- Window Behavior
- Focus

and try out the possibilities.

Don't have KDE on my current field machine, but that's what I recall

Comment: This would only work for top level windows. What I'm looking for would only be possible through Dolphin.

Comment: Went back to KDE's forum and let them know: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=289&t=165310&p=430527